# How do I specify port number for PuTTY to use with Windows cmd?

Tags: ssh, port, putty

I start most of my SSH connections with a windows command like this

```
cmd://"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh root@xxx.xx.xxx.xx
```

I assume this defaults to port 22. Now I need to connect on a different port. I tried

```
cmd://"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh root@xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxx
```

(port number on the end) but it won't allow the connection. I know the port number and IP are correct because if I fire up PuTTY and start a session with these details I can get in fine.

*p.s. If this is the wrong stackexchange for this question please don't destroy me, I did look for quite a long time before deciding to post here.*

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ok - I'm embarrassed. I just found the -P option which does exactly what I want.

```
cmd://"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh root@xxx.xx.xxx.xx -P xxx
```

is the correct syntax.